# Spring JPA transactional to avoid concurrency read / update

Tags: spring, jpa, concurrency, isolation

Using Spring boot and JPA/hibernate , I'm looking for a solution to avoid a table record being read by another process while I'm reading then updating an entity. Isolation levels Dirty read, Nonrepeatable read and Phantom read are not so clear for me. I mean if process #1 starts a read/update i don't want a process #2 to be able to read the old value (before updated by #1) and then update the structure with wrong values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isolation levels all prevent reading changes in different levels of strictness:

- Dirty Read -> reading not yet committed changes
- Nonrepeatable read -> querying the same row second time finds data changes
- Phantom read -> like previous but instead of data changes, it finds more data added ([more here](https://javamondays.com/transaction-isolation-levels/))

`Serializable` level, being the strictest, would prevent reading any changes yet, essentially resulting in sequential processing in DB (no concurrency) and would probably solve your problem

What you are looking for, if I understood correctly, is to block second process from doing any work until row update is complete - that is called row locking, and can be controlled directly as well (without setting serializable isolation)

See more about row locking with Spring JPA here: https://www.baeldung.com/java-jpa-transaction-locks

If it wasn't different process (different program) but just a different thread within the same Java program a simple `synchronized` would do the trick as well.